# Azure StaticWebApps and behavior of dotEnv to get environment variables

Tags: reactjs, azure, dotenv, azure-static-web-app

Hi I created a basic project using Azure static web apps and added 2 env files in it ".env" and ".env.production".
I observed all the new Azure staticwebapps were being started in "production environment" by default.

So let's say theres a key "REACT_APP_API_URL", which have different values in both the env files. I was able to switch keys using by setting the appropriate environment.

After that, I wanted to test if environment variables can override these .env files. So I in the pipeline I added the environment variable to modify the key.

```
trigger:
  - dev
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: "" 
      output_location: "build"
    env:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
      REACT_APP_API_URL: "Some value diff than .env and .env.prod"
```

It does override the .env files. Can someone kindly explain, how it is able to do that?
I have checked Dot env package doc and I still dont understand which values take priority in case both the .env files and environment variables are present.

Comment: Would also like to know this. Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to figure our the best practise. I am personally using .env file to set environment variables with local values that need to be run on localhost. I have passed production API keys via environment variables of Pipeline. Pipeline variables have higher precedence over .env files.